# How to implement SeekBar functionality in android

Tags: android, android-seekbar

Hi i am new for android and in my app i am using Seackbar 
please see my below image

My main problem is as like below image when user suppose reached to 0-3 then how can we recognize either he is reached to Exactly at "3" and suppose he is there B/W 3-5 how can i recognized

i am not understanding how can i improve this logic because i am very beginner in android  can some one explain me with some code

### code:-

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.seeckbar_layout);

        seekBar1=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                  boolean fromUser) {
        progressvalue = progress;
        System.out.println("Progress values is====>"+progressvalue);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar progress: "+progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar touch started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "seekbar touch stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: try to use Range SeekBar which helps to set thumb from both directions from starting point or from end point. If you need then i will provide you sample link

Comment: please provide sample link

Comment: Check below link it solve your range issue but to add line you need to customize that

https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-range-seekbar-tutorial/